# What is the part between the eyebrow tail and above the eyelid called?

Tags: human-anatomy, eyes, anatomy, human-eye

I need to know that anatomical name of the portion of the face between the eyebrow tail and the eyelid, as highlighted in red in the image below, as I need to refer to that particular area in writing succinctly and specifically and without any ambiguity or elaborate description. Upon thorough digging, I have found out that the lacrimal glands (responsible for producing tears) are present underneath the skin of the highlighted part but I fear that lacrimal fossa (where the aforementioned gland is contained) is not the correct term for the highlighted portion as refers to the specific part of the human skull and definitely not the highlighted skin-area pertaining to facial anatomy.

Further brainstorming has got me to the conclusion that the best way to denote these areas in a succinct, unambiguous way without being too "technical" is through "left/right brow bone" but I feel that there is a better/more-specific term for this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question can be found buried deep in the occuloplastic surgery literature.<sup>*</sup>

It's called... *the upper eyelid*. (!) Nowhere was it listed in numerous facial surface anatomy illustrations. I first encountered the name of the specific area [here](https://academic.oup.com/book/40818/chapter-abstract/348790599?redirectedFrom=fulltext). It refers to how facial tissue ages.

> The drooping brow and inelastic skin combine to cause upper eyelid tissue to drape over the lid margin, often obstructing the superior visual field.

The "eyelids" in common medical parlance usually refer to the structures that (normally) glide over the eye when blinking. The "eye" normally refers to the actual eyeball.

The occuloplastic literature, though, is necessarily more specific. The upper eyelid is the area between the eyebrow and the eyelid, the lower eyelid is the area that gets saggy in the elderly. The "eye" is the whole kit and kaboodle limited by the forehead above and the cheek below.

Droopy upper eyelid:
[image]

[This is a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1m0VW4FNiY&t=264s) of a Beverly Hills oculoplastic surgeon who, along with another plastic surgeon, has a show about botched plastic surgery (I believe it is called *Botched*.) In the video, you see him run his index finger over the area you asked about repeatedly, calling it the upper <s>eyebrow</s> (oops) *eyelid*.

<sup>*</sup><sup>Seriously. It took me a while to find it.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This area could be referred to technically as the **[zygomatic process of the frontal bone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygomatic_process)**. The frontal bone is the top/front part of your skull that comes down to the orbits of your eyes. It connects to the cheekbone (or zygomatic bone) via a protrusion (or process) forming the orbit of the eye. This is also a name for the skeletal anatomy rather than the skin you actually see, but I'm not sure there will be another specific term that doesn't refer to the anatomy of the skull itself.

For a less technical term, you could call it the upper/outer orbit of the eye. That will also refer to the bone, however, and may refer to a location above or below the eyebrow depending on if you're furrowing or arching your brow.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion to call it the "upper/outer orbit of the eye", would calling it the "brow ridge" or "supraorbital ridge" pinpoint to the area without making it too technical and avoiding ambiguity caused by your suggested term? Would really love your further inputs and suggestions on this!

Comment: @hecate Both of those would refer to the ridge over the eyes, but wouldn't be specific about lateral location. The brow ridge would span from temple to temple going over the nose, but wouldn't specifically refer to the outer parts of it. "Outer brow ridge" might be close enough without being too technical.

Comment: No one refers to it that way ("zygomatic process of the frontal bone"). It's also not referred to as any part of the orbit. Link to a reasonable source, please.

Comment: @anongoodnurse It is a technical anatomical term. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygomatic_process

Comment: Also, please note that on this site, we request that folks support their answers with reliable sources. Otherwise the answer is subject to deletion.